# Nodejs MSSQL package slow

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am using the [`MSSQL`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) package to connect to a SQL Server. I have got it to work but is extremely slow to retrieve even a few rows.

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var date

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   date=Date.now()
    var sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8")
    const config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'PASS',
        server: 'localhost\\SERVER', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
        database: 'DATABASE',
        pool: {
            max: 10,
            min: 5,
            idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
        }

    }

new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
    return pool.query('select field1 from TABLE1')

}).then(result => {
    console.dir(result)
    console.dir('This query took ' + (Date.now() - date) + 'ms to return ' + result.recordset.length + ' rows!');
}).catch(err => {
    // ... error checks
})
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

The output is:

```
{field1 :'row1'} ............ {field1:'row18'}
'This query took 5847ms to return 18 rows!'
```

This is a lot of time to retrieve just 18 rows.

Is this because I am using free SQL Server Express version in my Windows 10? I was planning to work with a lot of data and the data requires SQL Server database so I cannot use MongoDB.

Comment: you should connect SQL server at the time of start server. It take to much time to every request to connect and then fire your query to get result.

Comment: As already mentioned, that's not just retrieving rows, that is also connecting

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue with Typescript, here is how I solved it but not sure if it's good practice.

First I extracted config to it's own file this

```
import mssql from 'mssql';

const dbconfig = {
  server: 'u',
  user: 'u',
  password: 'u',
  database: 'u',
  options: { encrypt: true },
  pool: {
    min: 5
  }
};

export const db = new mssql.ConnectionPool(dbconfig);
```

secondly my route to it's own file too and that's how it looks

```
import express from 'express';
import mssql from 'mssql';


const router = express.Router();

export const route = (connection: any) => { // Note I am passing the connection here?
  router.get('/', (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    (async () => {
      try {

        const request = new mssql.Request(connection);
        const { recordset: cool } = await request.query(
          'Select * from tbl_categories'
        );
        res.send(cool);
      } catch (error) {
        next(error);
      }
    })();
  });
  return router
}
```

okay great, last step connection is created on the entry file app.ts / server.ts

```
import express from 'express';
import * as router from '../src/routes/test';
import morgan from 'morgan';

import { db } from './config.ts/dbconfig';

(async () => {
  const connection = await db.connect(); // Connection is created here
  const app = express();

  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  app.use(morgan('dev'));

  app.use('/tests', router.route(connection)); //Connection is passed to the route, problem solved


  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Yey!');
  });

  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server is running');
  });
})();
```

So by using async and await here, we're ensuring  that we have a connection before our server starts up. It can slow the app start up a bit cuz it still has to connect but once started, we are all set!